# Asynchronous Batch Updates With Large Files Not Working Properly

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, spring-data-jpa, jdbctemplate

I am trying to insert files which asynchronous batch updates but I am getting the following exception while inserting:

```
nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Large Objects may not be used in auto-commit mode.
```

Code Sample

```
  @Autowired
  private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  @Autowired
  private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedJdbcTemplate;

  @Value("${jdbc.batch_insert_size}")
  private int batchSize;

  private static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

  @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
  public void batchInsertAsync(List<User> users) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    
    String sql = "INSERT INTO `USER` (USERNAME, PASSWORD, FILE, UPDATEDTIME, USERTYPE, DATEOFBIRTH)"
        + " VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    final AtomicInteger sublists = new AtomicInteger();
    CompletableFuture[] futures = users.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(t -> sublists.getAndIncrement() / batchSize))
        .values()
        .stream()
        .map(ul -> runBatchInsert(ul, sql))
        .toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new);
    CompletableFuture<Void> run = CompletableFuture.allOf(futures);
    
    run.get();
    
    log.info("batchInsertAsync -> Total time in seconds: " + timer.getTotalTimeSeconds());
  }
  public CompletableFuture<Void> runBatchInsert(List<User> users, String sql) {
    return CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
      jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, new UserBatchPreparedStatementSetter(users));
    }, executor);
  }
```

```
public class UserBatchPreparedStatementSetter implements BatchPreparedStatementSetter{
  private List<User> users;
  
  public UserBatchPreparedStatementSetter(List<User> users) {
    super();
    this.users = users;
  }
  @Override
  public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) {
    
    try {
      User user = users.get(i);
      ps.setString(1, user.getUserName());
      ps.setString(2, user.getPassword());
      ps.setClob(3,org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.ClobProxy.generateProxy(user.getContent()));
      ps.setDate(4, user.getUpdatedTime() == null ? null : new java.sql.Date(user.getUpdatedTime().getTime()));
      ps.setString(5, user.getUserType().toString());
      ps.setDate(6, new java.sql.Date(user.getDateofBirth().getTime()));
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
  @Override
  public int getBatchSize() {
    return users.size();
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me how to use asynchronous batch updates with large files?

Thanks in advance

================================================================

Comment: Do you have hibernate autoCommit paramteer activated ? Else this might come from the "runAsync", the transaction might have to be inside the async rather than outside.

Comment: Yes, auto commit by default enabled with @Transactional annotation in spring data jpa. Ok, I will check it once. Thanks for suggestion!